# TikZ, tree, some childs without arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I wanted to create a tree structure and I'm almost done. Note that it is my first "project" with TikZ. 
My Problem: The childs of the first and part of the second level aren't connected with arrows. Can anyone help me? I don't see a difference compared to the particular last level.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',
edge from parent/.style={thick,draw=black!70,-latex},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=8.5cm},
,level distance =3.5cm,auto]

\tikzstyle{and}=[rectangle, rounded corners,thick,draw=black!75,top color=blue!10, bottom color=white,minimum size=5mm]
\tikzstyle{or}=[rectangle,rounded corners,thick,draw=black!75,top color=red!10, bottom color=white,minimum size=5mm]
\tikzstyle{terminal}=[rectangle, rounded corners, thick,draw=black!75, top color=green!5, bottom color=white,minimum size=5mm]
\tikzstyle{relation}=[rectangle,rounded corners,inner sep=2pt, thick,draw=black!75, fill=gray!20,minimum size=5mm, font =\scriptsize]

\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\footnotesize]


\node[and]  {\begin{tabular}{l} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{tabular}}
  child { [sibling distance = 2cm] node [and] (appr) {\begin{tabular}{l} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{tabular}}
  child{ node [terminal] (car) {2} }
  child{ node [relation] (rel) {\begin{tabular}{l} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{tabular}}  }
  child{ node [terminal] (zebra) {\begin{tabular}{l} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{tabular}}  }  } 
  child { [sibling distance = 6cm] node [or] (obstacle)  {\begin{tabular}{l} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{tabular}}
child{ [sibling distance = 2cm]  node [and] (ped_on_zebra) {\begin{tabular}{l} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{tabular}}  
    child{ node [terminal] (ped) {1} }
    child{ node [relation] (rel_1) {\begin{tabular}{l} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{tabular}}  }
    child{  node [terminal] (zebra_2) {\begin{tabular}{l} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{tabular}}  }  }
child { [sibling distance = 2cm]  node [and] (dog_on_zebra)  {\begin{tabular}{l} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{tabular}}   
    child{ node [terminal] (dog) {3} }
    child{ node [relation] (rel_2) {\begin{tabular}{l} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{tabular}}  }
    child{ node [terminal] (zebra_1) {\begin{tabular}{l} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{tabular}}  } }}
  ;

%Draw Relations
\path [dashed,-]
  (zebra) edge node [left] {} (rel)
  (rel) edge node [right] {} (car)

  (rel_1) edge node [left] {} (ped)
  (rel_1) edge node [right] {} (zebra_2)

  (rel_2) edge node [left] {} (dog)
  (rel_2) edge node [right] {} (zebra_1);

%create legend
\node [relation] (terminal)at (7,-2) {};
\node [right=0.2cm of terminal] {= Relation};
\node [terminal] (terminal)at (7,-1) {};
\node [right=0.2cm of terminal] {= Terminal-Node};
\node [and] (and) at (7,0) {};
\node [right=0.2cm of and] {= And-Node};
\node [or] (or) at (7,1) {} ;
\node [right=0.2cm of or] {= Or-Node};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I would post a picture but, I have not enough reputations.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrows are there but hidden behind the nodes.

The reason for this is wrong syntactical input. If there isn’t a node at the first place in a child TikZ doesn’t see a node as a child but whatever there is (you could put arbitrary stuff in there). Specify the `sibling distance` directly after the node (which is the parent of the siblings of which you specify the distance).

I took the liberty to clean-up the code a little bit and changes the process of the legend, it uses the `chains` library (which in turn uses the `positioning` library too).

By the way, tree nodes get named automatically, so there maybe a more automatic way to connect the last children, but that’s another story.

I haven’t added the `child anchor=north` option to the first level at it looks a little bit weird to me, but you might change that. In fact, you could just add `child anchor=north` to TikZ picture instead of the level styles.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  ->,
  >=stealth',
  edge from parent/.style={thick,draw=black!70,-latex},
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=8.5cm},
  level 2/.style={child anchor=north},
  level 3/.style={child anchor=north,sibling distance=2cm},
  level distance=3.5cm,
  auto,
  tree nodes/.style={
    shape=rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    thick,
    draw=black!75,
    minimum size=+5mm
  },
  and/.style     ={tree nodes, top color=blue!10, bottom color=white},
  or/.style      ={tree nodes, top color=red!10,  bottom color=white},
  terminal/.style={tree nodes, top color=green!5, bottom color=white},
  relation/.style={tree nodes, inner sep=2pt, fill=gray!20, font=\scriptsize},
  font=\footnotesize,
  every node/.append style={align=center}
]
\node              [and]                     {1 \\ 2 \\ 3}
  child {     node [and]      (appr)         {1 \\ 2 \\ 3}
    [sibling distance = 2cm]
    child {   node [terminal] (car)          {2}          }
    child {   node [relation] (rel)          {1 \\ 2 \\ 3}}
    child {   node [terminal] (zebra)        {1 \\ 2 \\ 3}}
  } 
  child {     node [or]       (obstacle)     {1 \\ 2 \\ 3}
    [sibling distance = 6cm]
    child {   node [and]      (ped_on_zebra) {1 \\ 2 \\ 3}
      child { node [terminal] (ped)          {1}          }
      child { node [relation] (rel_1)        {1 \\ 2 \\ 3}}
      child { node [terminal] (zebra_2)      {1 \\ 2 \\ 3}}
    }
    child   { node [and]      (dog_on_zebra) {1 \\ 2 \\ 3}
      child { node [terminal] (dog)          {3}          }
      child { node [relation] (rel_2)        {1 \\ 2 \\ 3}}
      child { node [terminal] (zebra_1)      {1 \\ 2 \\ 3}}
    }
  };

\path [dashed,-]
  (rel) edge (zebra)
        edge (car)

  (rel_1) edge (ped)
          edge (zebra_2)

  (rel_2) edge (dog)
          edge (zebra_1);

\begin{scope}[shift={(7,1)}, node distance=+1cm, on grid, label position=right, start chain=ch going above]
  \foreach \sStyle/\tText in {relation/Relation, terminal/Terminal-Node, and/And-Node, or/Or-Node} 
    \node[
     on chain=ch,
     \sStyle,
     label={= \tText}
    ] {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The arrows are there, but hidden behind the nodes. Shorten the edges or change the anchor, so that it's not the center, such as by `node [and,anchor=north east]`:

```
\node[and]  {\begin{tabular}{l} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{tabular}}
  child { [sibling distance = 2cm] node [and,anchor=north east] (appr) 
    {\begin{tabular}{l} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{tabular}}
  child{ node [terminal] (car) {2} }
  child{ node [relation] (rel) {\begin{tabular}{l} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{tabular}}  }
  child{ node [terminal] (zebra) {\begin{tabular}{l} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{tabular}}  }  } 
  child { [sibling distance = 6cm] node [or,anchor=north west] (obstacle)
    {\begin{tabular}{l} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{tabular}}
...
```

[image]

Comment: Tanks, works great!

Comment: Now there occured another proble, if I use [anchor = north] (becaus I want the arrow to target at the top), the lowest level is not on the same level anymore, because I did not use anchor=north. but if i use anchor=north, the nodes are not centered anymore, cause the tip of the arrows are all on the same height

Comment: @Stefan Perhaps try to isolate the problem in a new and possible even smaller example and post it as a new separate question, as the original issue of missing arrow tips is solved. This site doesn't work with chronologic threads, it's pure: one specific question, some answers. Another specific question (can be related, add a link), other answers to that one.

Comment: I did open a new Question, thanks.http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123244/tikz-childs-not-exactly-on-the-same-level

Comment: @Stefan The `[sibling distance=<dim>]` is at the wrong position syntactically. Position it after the `child` or after the first node (aka in front of the siblings) Then the edge will be connected with the node and not simply the child coordinate.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, thanks a lot! Actually this was the core of my problem!