# Tikz, childs not exactly on the same level

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having trouble arranging my child nodes. They don't seem to be centered, horizontally, if use the anchor=north setting. It looks like they are arrange according to their top edge of the node, but i would like to have them centered, so that the connection between the childs a parallel.
I'll hope you understand what I mean!

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',
 edge from parent/.style={thick,draw=black!70,-latex},
 level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
 ,level distance =4.5cm,auto,scale=0.75,transform shape]


\tikzstyle{and}=[rectangle, rounded corners,thick,draw=black!75,top color=blue!10, bottom color=white,minimum size=5mm]
\tikzstyle{or}=[rectangle,rounded corners,thick,draw=black!75,top color=red!10, bottom color=white,minimum size=5mm]
\tikzstyle{terminal}=[rectangle, rounded corners, thick,draw=black!75, top color=green!5, bottom color=white,minimum size=5mm]
\tikzstyle{relation}=[rectangle,rounded corners,inner sep=2pt, thick,draw=black!75, top color=gray!20, bottom color=white,minimum size=5mm, font =\scriptsize]

\node [or,right=6.75cm of obstacle] (obstacle1)  {\begin{tabular}{l} Obstacle at \\ zebra crossing \end{tabular}}
  child{ [sibling distance = 8cm]  node [and,anchor=north] (ped_on_zebra) {\begin{tabular}{l} Pedestrian \\ on zebra crossing \end{tabular}}  
  child{ node [terminal,anchor=north] (ped1) {Pedestrian} }
  child{ node [relation,anchor=north] (rel_11) {\begin{tabular}{l} dist., \\ vel. \\ orient.\end{tabular}}  }
  child{  node [terminal,anchor=north] (zebra_21) {\begin{tabular}{l} Zebra \\ crossing \end{tabular}}  }  }
;
\path
(rel_11) edge node [left] {} (ped1)
(rel_11) edge node [right] {} (zebra_21);


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Well, then don’t use the option `anchor=north` but `anchor=center` (which is the default). This positions the children at the same height.

Comment: The problem is, that I want to have the anchor at north. Is there another possibility?

Comment: Actually I saw your comment in my other question, now i don't have to use anchor=north ;-), Thanks!

Comment: Hi Stefan, and welcome to the site. I'm having a bit of trouble recreating your situation on my machine. Could you turn your code snippet into a
compilable `.tex` file, starting with 
`\documentclass` and ending with 
`\end{document}`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `anchor=north` for `terminal` nodes and connect them with an horizontal line you have two options:

1- Make all `terminal` and `relation` nodes have same height with a `minimum height` large enough. This way, they will be aligned according `north` anchor but also their `center`.

[image]

2- Don't touch `terminal` and `relation` nodes height but draw an horizontal line between them which it's different from a line between their centers. I think it's not so nice but possible:

```
\path
(rel_11.west|-ped1) edge node [left] {} (ped1)
(rel_11.east|-ped1) edge node [right] {} (zebra_21.west|-ped1);
```

Red line is drawn between centers and green line is drawn with previous command.

[image]

Next code is a modified version of your one. What's different?

1- All styles are defined inside `[...]` after `\begin{tikzpicture}` and avoiding `\tikzstyle`

2- All your nodes share same options except `top color`, so you can declare a general style (`mynode`) with one argument and use it to define `terminal`, `relation`, ... styles.

3- `mynode` includes options `text width` and `align` which allow to avoid using `tabular` inside node's text. You can still use `\\` to break lines or left LaTeX to do it for you.

4- I've suppressed `node [left] {}` from `edge` path because they are superfluous in this figure.

5- I've suppressed `,right=6.75cm of obstacle` because there is no `obstacle` node in this example.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',
 edge from parent/.style={thick,draw=black!70,-latex},
 level 1/.style = {sibling distance=4cm},
 level distance = 4.5cm,auto,scale=0.75,transform shape,
 mynode/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, thick, minimum size = 5mm, text width = 3cm, align = center, draw=black!75, bottom color=white, top color=#1},
 and/.style = {mynode=blue!10},
 or/.style = {mynode=red!10},
 terminal/.style = {mynode=green!10},
 relation/.style = {mynode=gray!10, font=\scriptsize},
]

\node [or] (obstacle1)  {Obstacle at \\ zebra crossing}
  child{ [sibling distance = 8cm]  node [and,anchor=north] (ped_on_zebra) {Pedestrian \\ on zebra crossing}  
  child{ node [terminal,anchor=north] (ped1) {Pedestrian} }
  child{ node [relation,anchor=north] (rel_11) {dist., \\ vel. \\ orient.}  }
  child{  node [terminal,anchor=north] (zebra_21) {Zebra \\ crossing}  }  }
;
\path[red]
(rel_11) edge (ped1)
(rel_11) edge (zebra_21);
\path[green]
(rel_11.west|-ped1) edge (ped1)
(rel_11.east|-ped1) edge (zebra_21.west|-ped1);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```